# Force Azure Worker Role Project Carry extra dll

Tags: azure, reflection, dll, deployment

I'm doing some reflection based work on azure and I would like to know if its possible to "force" the deploy project to carry the "extras" (not directally referenced, but necessary) dlls along with my default dlls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upload the dlls to a blob storage. Then in your on start of role, download the files into the required folder. You may also make use of startup tasks running with elevated privileges.

Comment: looks like a very clean approach! i will use it... make the project carry the dlls doesnt sound good compared to this...

Answer (score 0):

After adding them to whatever project folder you have, just set "copy local" to true.

Comment: did not work... i created a folder in the WorkerRole project called "External Refs", added each dll, set them to copy always, but it did not take... when i check the package, the only present dlls are those being used as references...